# node-red requireHttps does not work, accessing http does not redirect to https

Tags: https, node-red

I am trying to expose a node-red instance into the internet by using HTTPS, following [this tutorial](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/securing-node-red-ssl/).
In short, I added (uncommented) the following lines inside node-red's `setting.js` :

```
var fs = require("fs");

requireHttps: true,

https: {
       key: fs.readFileSync('privatekey.pem'),
       cert: fs.readFileSync('certificate.pem')
},
```

The https worked as expected. However, the http does not redirect to https and instead gives `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Can anybody help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working as designed, Node-RED only listens on one port at a time so when configured to use HTTPS it will not respond to HTTP traffic.

This means you cannot redirect from one to the other with just Node-RED. A better solution is to use something like nginx to reverse proxy for Node-RED and have it handle the redirect.

From the article you linked to:

> Note:I didn’t get this to work with SSL so you may need to skip this

You can see that the author also was mistaken and couldn't get this to work.
.

Comment: if that's the case, what is the function of `requireHttps: true` on the setting file?

Comment: When behind a reverseProxy it will read the `X-Forwarded-Proto`  header and if needed send a redirect to HTTPS

Answer (score 0):

This does the job without any other web server.

Based on [Node-RED documentation: Embedding into an existing app](https://nodered.org/docs/embedding), node-RED runs with managed http and https servers provided by node.js.

According to the tuto you've given, you don't have to overide settings.js.

To make this work, you have to create your own project :

```
$ mkdir myNodeREDProject
$ cd myNodeRedProject
$ touch index.js
$ npm init
$ npm install node-red
```

Copy your ssl private key and certificate into the `myNodeREDProject` folder.

Edit `index.js` and copy the following :

```
const https = require('https');
const express = require("express");
const RED = require("node-red");
const fs = require('fs');

const HTTP_PORT = 8080;
const HTTPS_PORT = 8443;

// Create an Express app
const app = express();

// at the top of routing: this is the http redirection to https part ;-)
app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.protocol === 'https') return next();
  res.redirect(`https://${req.hostname}:${HTTPS_PORT}${req.url}`);
});

// Add a simple route for static content served from 'public'
app.use("/",express.static("public"));

// Create a https server
const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./privatekey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./certificate.pem')
};
const httpsServer = https.createServer(options, app);
// create a http server
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);

// Create the settings object - see default settings.js file for other options
const settings = {
  httpAdminRoot:"/red",
  httpNodeRoot: "/api",
  userDir:"./nodered/",
  functionGlobalContext: { }    // enables global context
};

// Initialise the runtime with a server and settings
RED.init(httpsServer,settings);

// Serve the editor UI from /red
app.use(settings.httpAdminRoot,RED.httpAdmin);

// Serve the http nodes UI from /api
app.use(settings.httpNodeRoot,RED.httpNode);

httpsServer.listen(HTTPS_PORT);
httpServer.listen(HTTP_PORT);

// Start the runtime
RED.start();
```

Finally, to run the node-RED application :

```
$ node index.js   # MAGIC !!!
```

Please, don't hesitate to correct me if I'm wrong, I've tested it on my Linux server.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: I see.. in this case since the node-red is "wrapped" inside express, the https redirection is handled by the express app, right? I'll try this later, thanks!

Comment: Yes, express is the way to go :-)